# Add custom attribute for users created from AWS cognito console - is it right to use Auth.CompleteNewPassword?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have created a user from AWS Cognito console. On user's first signin through my application, he will be forced to change the password.
My requirement is I should be able to add Custom Attribute when the user changes the password and click on change password.

**What I did:**
I could add custom attribute through code for the users who are signing up directly from my app. There, I used handleSignup() function to intercept and added custom attribute.

Based on above logic, I tried using handleSignIn() and intercept submission of changed password(The code is provided below). But when I click signin using temporary password (before the prompt for new password appears) , my code is erroring out saying newPassword is undefined. Based on my understanding, I have not entered newpassword yet and hence it is erroring out. So, I think I am invoking Auth.CompleteNewPassword() at wrong place. Can someone please suggest the right thing to do based on my requirements and what I tried?. Thank you

```
async handleSignIn(formData){
            let {username, password} = formData; 
           
            return Auth.signIn(username, password)
            .then(user => {
                if (user.challengeName === 'NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED') {
                    const { requiredAttributes } = user.challengeParam; 
                    //custom attribute logic goes here;
                    Auth.completeNewPassword(
                        user,               // the Cognito User Object
                        newPassword,       // the new password
                        customAttribute
                    ).then(user => {
                   
                        console.log(user);
                    }).catch(e => {
                      console.log(e);
                    });
                } else {
                    // other situations
                }
            }).catch(e => {
                console.log(e);
            });
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to collect a new password from the user after they sign in and are required to change the password. Once you have the new password then call `Auth.completeNewPassword`. Not straight after Sign In.

Here is some basic code to show how to do:

**First attempt sign in**

`let cognitoUser = await Auth.signIn(params); //where params is user / pass`

**If new password required, set the cognito user into state**

```
const [authUser, setAuthUser] = useState({});

...

if (cognitoUser && cognitoUser.challengeName === "NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED") {
    setAuthUser(cognitoUser);
}
```

**In the UI you would show a new password field. When user submits:**

```
let cognitoUser = await Auth.completeNewPassword(authUser, newPassword);
```